# How to combine multiple criteria in OR query dynamically in Play Morphia

Tags: playframework-1.x, morphia

I am trying to use a kind of builder pattern to build an OR query using multiple criteria depending upon the scenario. An example is

```
    public class Stylist extends Model {

      public String firstName;

      public String lastName;

      public String status;

      ...

      }
```

I would like to search Stylist collection if the first name or last name matches a given string and also status matches another string. I am writing the query as follows:

```
      MorphiaQuery query = Stylist.q();
      if (some condition) {
      query.or(query.criteria("status").equal("PendingApproval"), query.criteria("status").equal(EntityStatus.ACTIVE));    
      }

      if (some other condition as well) {
      query.or(query.criteria("firstName").containsIgnoreCase(name), query.criteria("lastName").containsIgnoreCase(name));
      }
```

When both the conditions are met, I see that query contains only the criteria related to firstName and lastName i.e. different OR criteria are not added/appended but overwritten. It's quite different from filter criteria where all the different filter conditions are appended and you can easily build queries containing multiple AND conditions.

I can solve the problem by putting my conditions differently and building my queries differently but doesn't seem to be an elegant way. Am I doing something wrong ?

I am using Play! Framework 1.2.4 and Play Morphia module version 1.2.5a

**Update**

To put it more clearly, I would like to AND multiple OR queries. Concretely, in the above mentioned scenario, I would like to

I would like to search for Stylists where :

```
firstName or lastName contains supplied name AND

status equals ACTIVE or PENDING_APPROVAL.
```

I have been able to construct the query directly on Mongo shell through :

db.stylists.find({$and: [{$or : [{status: "PENDING_APPROVAL"}, {status : "ACTIVE"}]},{$or : [{firstName : { "$regex" : "test" , "$options" : "i"}}, {lastName : { "$regex" : "test" , "$options" : "i"}}]}] }).pretty();

But have not able to achieve the same through Query API methods. Here is my attempt :

```
    Query<Stylist> query = MorphiaPlugin.ds().find(Stylist.class);

    CriteriaContainer or3 = query.or(query.criteria("firstName").containsIgnoreCase(name), query.criteria("lastName").containsIgnoreCase(name));

    CriteriaContainer or4 = query.or(query.criteria("status").equal("PENDING_APPROVAL"), query.criteria("status").equal("ACTIVE"));

    query.and(or3, or4);
```

query.toString() results in following output : { "$or" : [ { "status" : "PENDING_APPROVAL"} , { "status" : "ACTIVE"}]}

Not sure, where am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess there could be 2 ways to handle your case:

first, use `List<Criteria>`

```
MorphiaQuery query = Stylist.q();
List<Criteria> l = new ArrayList<Criteria>()

if (some condition) {
  l.add(query.criteria("status").equals("PendingApproval");
  l.add(query.criteria("status").equal(EntityStatus.ACTIVE));
}

if (some other conditional as well) {
  l.add(query.criteria("firstName").containsIgnoreCase(name));
  l.add(query.criteria("lastName").containsIgnoreCase(name));
}

query.or(l.toArray());
```

Second, use `CritieriaContainer`

```
MorphiaQuery query = Stylist.q();
CriteriaContainer cc = null;

if (some condition) {
  cc = query.or(query.criteria("status").equal("PendingApproval"), query.criteria("status").equal(EntityStatus.ACTIVE));
}

if (some other condition) {
  if (null != cc) query.or(cc, query.criteria("firstName").containsIgnoreCase(name), query.criteria("lastName").containsIgnoreCase(name));
  else query.or(query.criteria("firstName").containsIgnoreCase(name), query.criteria("lastName").containsIgnoreCase(name));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @green, it solves the problem. My question should have been rephrased a bit like : How can I AND multiple OR queries using Morphia ? Though this approach solves the problem but it involves passing CriteriaContainer objects across several methods. Can I get a CriteriaContainer object from query object ?

Comment: Sorry @green, False alarm. Both the options suggested by you didn't work as expected. It still seems to ignore the earlier criteria (related to status) and only takes into account the one related to firstName / lastName.

Comment: btw, there is a thread on [link](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3327) which seems to suggest that ANDing of multiple OR queries is still not supported in a straight forward manner.